# Error on iPhone animation project

Tags: iphone

I don't understand why this won't work, I keep getting an error:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([JackAnimationAppDelegate class]));
}
```

Here is my code:

```
#import "JackAnimationViewController.h"

@implementation JackAnimationViewController
@synthesize color;

- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

    color.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenDim.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenPressed.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowDim.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"YellowPressed.png"],nil];

            [color setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
            color .animationDuration = 4;
            [color startAnimating]; 
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [self setColor:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? That's the first thing you should tell us.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is Xcode version problem.

Application created with Xcode4 or above.

But now you opened the application with Lessor version of Xcode.

Install the new version Xcode , solves your problem

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess problem is not wit your code but its with your Xcode. Did you recently made transition from Xcode 4.0 to 4.3 or vice versa?